# Saving to Rails Database from Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rubygems

I am trying to make this as generic as possible to help others.

I am retrieving from a gem certain data like so:

```
gem = Gem::Client.new.get_country_profile
```

and get_country_profile returns

```
gem.id  // "23"
gem.country // "Germany"
gem.motto // 'Beer'
```

It is sent as an object and I can iterate over it. I create a migration model and controller to handle all this such that

```
@country_data = @country.country_data
```

is created to handle saving the data from the gem.

So how do I save the data from the gem to database?  The below doesn't work.

```
def save_profile
 @country_data = @country.country_data //Country_data.all doesn't work either.
 @country_data.each do |a|
  gem = Gem::Client.new.get_country_profile
  gem.id = a.id
  gem.country = a.country
  gem.motto = a.motto
  a.save!
 end
end
```

Here is the model:

```
class CountryDataController < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :country
end
```

Here is the boilerplate scaffold controller:

```
class CountryDataController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_country_datas
  before_action :set_country_data

  def index
    @country_datas = @country.country_datas
  end

  def show
    @country_datas = @country.country_datas
  end

  def new
      @country_data = @country.country_datas.build
  end

  def create
    # @country_data = @country_data.countries.build(country_params)

     @country_data = Country_data.all
        @country_data.each do |a|
        gem = Gem::Client.new.get_country_profile
        gem.id = a.id
        gem.country = a.country
        gem.motto = a.motto
        a.save!
      end
    end

  private
    def set_country_datas
      @country_datas = Country.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_country_data
      @country_data = @country.country_data.find(params[:id])
    end

    def country_params
      params.require(:country_data).permit(:id, :country, :motto)
    end
end
```

Comment: @country_data = CountryData.all  //it should work if its a model.  It would  be great if you post some model code also.

Comment: OK, I'll add model and controller. It's all boilerplate scaffolding.